# Daily practice of a Kundalini yogi

Tags: practice, yoga, kundalini

What are the daily rituals/practices to be performed by an already Kundalini activated person.

Comment: Find a living teacher. Do not attempt things on your own.

Comment: from your guru..,

Comment: Once the Kundalini is awake the Yogi then practices to move it upwards. towards the Sahasrara Chakra by piercing one Chakra after another.

Comment: Do not attempt these things on your own.